# New ASP.NET Core MVC application cannot find view

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm brand new to ASP.NET Core. I use Visual Studio and upon generating a new ASP.NET Core MVC web app project, I feel like I should be able to run it without touching a single line of code to reveal the boiler plate application, but I instead get an error where it states it can't locate the `Index` files.

Again, I haven't touched any of the code and the files are there.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

Here's my `Program.cs` file:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

HomeController.cs

```
using BulkyBookWeb.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace BulkyBookWeb.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

launchSettings.json...

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59821",
      "sslPort": 44390
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "BulkyBookWeb": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7273;http://localhost:5273",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You also need to provide the Controller code.

Comment: Could you pls share your Startup.cs? Or if you use asp.net 6 , pls share your Program.cs.

Comment: Just updated the question with the code currently in that file. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @ACDev, the middlewares look all right in your Program.cs. Did you try other url, like `Home/Pricavy`? Can it work fine? Maybe share your HomeController will be helpful.

Comment: I have tried those other URLs and that doesn't seem to work either. I just provided the HomeController above and also provided the launchSettings.json for good measure.

Comment: Looks like it is a just a new project without any error. I think you can firstly try to clean and rebuild the project(right click the project and choose clean/rebuild). Even try relaunch the visual studio.  If still does not work, pls create a new .net 6 project and check if it work or not. If create a new project also cannot work, I think your visual studio may be modified.

Comment: Okay. Those steps for clean/reclean and closing/reopening visual studio didn't work. I've tried creating a new project a few times with the same issue. You think I should just try uninstalling/reinstalling Visual Studio? I'm brand new to ASP.Net so I wouldn't be losing much from restarting.

Comment: Do you also get the same problem in other versions of the Asp.net core project(like asp.net core 5)?

Comment: I have version 6. When creating a new project, it doesn't give me the option from the dropdown to choose a different version. I just now started learning this framework so I haven't interacted with any other version.

Comment: Hi @ACDev, Yes, if all the solution cannot help you, i think maybe caused by the visual studio itself. Because I think you just create a mvc project without coding anything.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem. Install Version 17.1.1 for Visual Studio 2022 fix the problem for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce; however, check out your version of dotnet framework.

See: [View Index Not Found But Actually Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71370727/the-view-index-was-not-found-but-it-actually-exist)