# The view 'Index' was not found, but it actually exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Appears:

> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
> /Views/Films/Index.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml

Although the file is present on the first path:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNjyO.jpg)

By Default, As the initial page action: "Index" Controller: "Films"

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Films}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Controller himself:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? creationTeamId)
{
    var dBOnlineCinemaContext = _context.Films.Include(f => f.CreationTeam);
    if (creationTeamId == null) //start Page
        return View();
        //
}
```

If right-click on the method and select "Go to View", redirects to the desired View

Comment: This is odd.... Do any of the other pages work?

Comment: @Stefan, no. Such a feeling, that method View() works incorrect

Comment: Can you provide proof (possibly a screenshot) that the file is there? This must be something trivial - something we're overlooking.

Comment: do include a screenshot of solution explorer > views folder

Comment: I have modified the post by adding a screenshot

Comment: Right click on view file and open properties. Please check that build actions should be "Content".

Comment: @DeepakThakur, bulid action is "Content", but doesn't work

Comment: I think your problem is `Index(int? creationTeamId)`, the param should be `id` instead of `creationTeamId`

Comment: @Nick Vu, still not working

Comment: What is your controller name?

Comment: @NickVu FilmsController.cs

Comment: @Skalar Can you post the startup file pls?

Comment: Can you post screenshot or code of your csproj file? The part where this View file location is mentioned in csproj code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the SDK installed is compatible with visual studio.

run the command below to see SDKs installed.:

```
dotnet --info
```

The SDK 6.0.200 is not compatible with Visual Studio 2022 17.0.6.
See [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0)

*To solve you have to use a visual studio compatible with the SDK installed.*

I've had this problem too, to solve you can:

-Install the Visual Studio 17.0.1 with is compatible with 6.0.200 SDK, or

-Remove the .net SDK 6.0.200 and use 6.0.102 with visual studio 17.0.6.

For those who find this problem in future versions, try to use the compatible version of Visual Studio and .net SDK, as shown [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) in Visual Studio support.

Comment: I ran into same problem. True for macOS too. 2022 for Mac is still in RC. You cannot select .NET 6.0 when creating new projects with VS for Mac 2019. You can manually switch to 6.0 after creating project , and you can even build it without errors. But you will get the error when running it. In fact there's a warning saying that 6.0 is not supported by the version of VS for Mac.